# Issue while reading solr indexed data

Tags: solr, solrj

I have indexed pojos in solr successfully but while reading from solr my output is wrong.
Maybe the way I am printing is not correct. Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?
My code is as follows:

```java
List<SampleDocument> foundDocuments = response.getBeans(SampleDocument.class);  
for(SampleDocument docs:foundDocuments) {
    System.out.println(docs.getTitle());
}
```

After printing the output I get is all Null.

SampleDocument.java

```java
package solrobj.Asolrobj;

import java.util.List;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field;

public class SampleDocument {
    private int id;
    private String title;

    public SampleDocument() {
        // required for solrj to make an instance
    }

    public SampleDocument(int id, String title) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Field("title")
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Field("tid")
    public void setId(int id)  {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Schema.xml

```xml
<field name="tid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"    multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

error
```

Comment: Would you also share the code of your SampleDocument and your schema.xml? That would be helpful in order to check if the POJO attributes and schema fields match.

Comment: @cheffe I have shared my SampleDocument.java and Schema.xml

Comment: The code of your POJO and your schema do not align. In your POJO you write that _title_ is a simple `String`, but in your schema your write that the according field is `multiValued="true"`. That cannot work. Additionally the types of _id_ do not match, in your POJO it is `int` in your schema it is `string`, you should see exceptions.

Comment: @cheffe when i write <field name="tid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"    multiValued="false" /> in my schema.xml, i'm not able to start solr. it is showing error.

Comment: main problem is i'm not able to declare unique key type=int. @cheffe

Comment: Could you post your _whole_ schema.xml? If you cannot declare type int, you might have left it out in the `<types>` element.